# Installation procedure for cassandra, Datastax Enterprise and community and Opscenter in Ubuntu

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Hi I'm a Java programmer and new to Cassandra, as per my project requirement I need to install in Ubuntu machine and start playing with it. By reviewing lot of websites I got a conclusion that, to setup Cassandra need to install cassandra, Datastax Enterprise and community and Opscenter.
But I don't know which s/w need to install first and what is the configuration I need to do with that. So please some one can guide me directly or please suggest me good websites for simple procedure into setup Cassandra in Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Installing Datastax Community follow this instruction [set](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html?pagename=docs&version=1.2&file=#cassandra/install/installDeb_t.html)

And for Datastax Enterprise, simply follow [this](http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.2/install/install_deb_pkg)